# Marionette CompositeView renders itself for each Model in Collection instead of ItemView (Marionette Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

Basically, I'm trying to render a CompositeView as a simple four-column list with a table header, where each model in a collection is rendered into a  and appended to the . I'm following [an example of Derick's](http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/me4NK/) quite closely with only a little variation, but unfortunately have gotten some pretty strange results.

Instead of rendering each itemView, the view instead references itself and re-renders for each item in the collection, producing a new table and table head. Before that, It was rendering the compositeView in itself.

I have an itemView, the template of which is a group of  items, and a compositeView that references it which is a table

The CompositeView:

```
class App.module('Views.Parts').Index extends Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView
   template: 'parts/index'
   itemView: App.Views.Parts.Part
   tagName: 'table'
   itemViewContainer: 'tbody'
   appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView, index)->
           collectionView.$el.append(itemView.el)
```

The ItemView:

```
class App.module('Views.Parts').Part extends Backbone.App.ItemView
       tagName: 'tr'
       template: 'parts/part'
       events:
               "click .destroy": "destroy"
       destroy: (e) ->
               e.preventDefault()
               @model.destroy()
       onRender: ->
               @stickIt()
```

The Controller

```
class App.Controllers.Parts
       constructor: ->
               @parts = new App.Collections.Parts
               @parts.reset(App.parts)
               App.parts = null

       showView: (view)->
               App.mainRegion.show view

       index: ->
               view = new App.Views.Parts.Index
                       collection: @parts
               @showView view
```

I have also heard that declaring an ItemView before the CompositeView is necessary--however since it is a Marionette Rails project, the views are actually living in different directories. Would I have to declare their order or bind them to each other accordingly in another way?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to have `itemViewContainer` AND `appendHtml`. Try removing the latter and your views should render properly.

Comment: Gracias. We ended up changing the declaration order via the require tree which fixed our rendering issue (the table works!). We still have both `itemViewContainer` & `appendHtml`. What sort of issues might this cause later down the line?

Comment: Well for starters, your appendHtml code correspond to the default behavior, so it's not needed. It might lead to issues because they're both telling the collection view where to add a new item view, which could cause conflicts.

Comment: Just writing to confirm that taking out the appendHtml code still rendered everything as expected. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

*TL;DR Marionette.CompositeView* uses itself as the item view type if none defined. Set the itemView property on prototype to make it use the correct item view

#### Problem

In our case issue was that Marionette gets the *ItemView* of a *CompositeView* by the [following logic](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/3761df5c72a401f71b43d9653b91efc6552497b9/lib/backbone.marionette.js#L1770):

```
getItemView: function(item){
  var itemView = Marionette.getOption(this, "itemView") || this.constructor;

  if (!itemView){
    throwError("An `itemView` must be specified", "NoItemViewError");
  }

  return itemView;
}
```

We had defined the *CompositeView* as:

```
class sm.Views.GreetingPicker extends Marionette.CompositeView
  template: 'greeting_picker'
  el: '.message-choice'
  itemView: sm.Views.WelcomeMessage
```

When the *CompositeView*, *ItemView* & *Layout* that tied them together were in one file (served by Rails using Sprockets), the file loaded all at once and there was no problem.

After I split up the *Layout*, *CompositeView* & *ItemView*, the *CompositeView*'s appendHtml's both arguments were of the same type as CompositeView. This was caused by the Marionette's logic mentioned in the beginning.

#### Solution

In the initializer set the *itemView* property on constructor manually. Like this:

```
class sm.Views.GreetingPicker extends Marionette.CompositeView
  initialize: ->
    @constructor::['itemView'] = sm.Views.WelcomeMessage
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I was just tackling a similar problem and came across this solution right after I posted my question, naturally.