# Marionette CompositeView as itemView of its own itemView (circular recursion?)

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, marionette

Here's an interesting one. I've got two CompositeViews, `CategoriesView` and `CategoryView` and I've got a nested collection of categories, where each category may have 0 or more children. I'd like to render the collection so that any category with children uses `CategoriesView` as its `itemView` and any category without uses `CategoryView`. Ideally, I'd like to have `CategoryView` use `CategoriesView` as its `itemView`, and vice versa. So:

```
+---------------------------------+
| CategoriesView: Title           | <- 4 children
|---------------------------------|
| CategoryView: item 1            | <- 0 children
| CategoryView: item 2            | <- 0 children
| CategoryView: item 3            | <- 0 children
| +-----------------------------+ |
| | CategoriesView: title       | | <- 10 children
| |-----------------------------| |
| | CategoryView: item 5        | |
...
```

The issue I'm running into is that I can't define `CategoryView`'s `itemView` property as `CategoriesView` because that object is defined later in the script file. This causes `CompositeView` to use itself as the `itemView`.

```
var CategoryView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: catTpl,
    tagName: 'li',
    itemView: CategoriesView,
    itemViewContainer: '.panel-group',
    initialize: function() {
        if (this.model.get('children').length) {
            this.collection = this.model.get('children');
        }
    },
    onRender: function() {
        if (!this.collection) {
            this.$(".panel-group").remove();
        }
    }
});

var CategoriesView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: groupTpl,
    className: "panel panel-default",
    itemView: CategoryView,
    itemViewContainer: '.panel-body ul',
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = this.model.get('children');
    }
});
```

(Side note: I'm using Bootstrap's `panel` and `collapse` to render each category group as its own panel.)

Right now, it renders the top level categories as panels, and everything underneath as lists.

Is there a better way to handle this kind of nested view relationship? I'm sure I could hack something together if needed, but I'd rather do it the "right" way. :) Or should I just forget it and go the nested list route by omitting `itemView` on `CategoryView` so it uses itself?

Comment: I just found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127436/marionette-compositeview-renders-itself-for-each-model-in-collection-instead-of#20049509) which answers the undefined itemView question and has put me on the right track. I'll update with a real answer when I get this fully working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was overriding the `getItemView` function to return the appropriate `ItemView` class:

```
// Renders a simple list item
var CategoryView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: catTpl,
    tagName: "li"
});

// Renders a Panel with heading and body and container for list items
var CategoriesView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: groupTpl,
    className: "panel panel-default",
    itemViewContainer: '.panel-body ul',
    // Reuse this as the itemView if we need to render a sub-list
    getItemView: function(item) {
        if (item.get('children').length == 0) {
            return CategoryView;
        } else {
            return this.constructor;
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = this.model.get('children');
    }
});

// Renders the outermost container
return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: mainTpl,
    className: "carousel slide",
    attributes: {
        "data-interval": false,
        "data-wrap": false
    },
    itemView: CategoriesView,
    itemViewContainer: '#categories'
});
```

This works really well and allows me to have a somewhat more complex layout that doesn't quite fit into the traditional tree/leaf pattern that CompositeViews allow for out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var CategoryView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // don't define the itemView here...
});

var CategoriesView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // edited for brevity
    itemView: CategoryView,
    // edited for brevity
});

CategoryView.itemView = CategoriesView
```

Comment: Thanks! This definitely would take care of one of the problems I was having (assigning an itemView to a class defined later in the file), but wasn't exactly what I needed to happen. See my answer below.